# How should I approach this multi-classification problem?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to think of a potential way to predict an ID value given text data. The data is broken by:

Group: A 4 digit number in which a group of IDs exists in

ID: 13 Digit Number that is the Group Number + a Unique Value

Text: Words coming from documents.

Goal: is to predict an ID number given only the text from a document.

The data that I have has about 1200 different IDs while there are only 140 different groups. The document term matrix is about 186 columns wide with about 20,000 rows. I have a lot more data I could include. I had created a simple neural net to predict the Group number with 70% accuracy. My idea is to use this model first to predict the group number and then build separate models for each group to narrow the amount of IDs in the prediction. A final model would be trained and would be used to predict the ID. Below is a drawing of what I had in mind. Is this similar to stacking in ensemble learning? I am relatively new to machine learning and I am trying to think of different ways to approach this problem.

[image]

Am I on the right path or is there a better way of doing this? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on how well you think you can infer the `group_number` and `unique_value` from the text. Does the `unique_value` depend at all on the `group_number`? If so, then you will likely want to predict the `group_number` first and use that in the prediction of the `unique_value` - as you have suggested doing for each unique group number. You will also have to consider the amount of data you have for each given group and if it's enough to train respective models. Give it a shot, and if it doesn't work, try a single neural network where you enter the text and the group number you've already predicted!

Good Luck!